# Selenium & Chrome using too much memory

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium/C# and Chrome to scrap a website, There is a list that I need to scroll through, and scrap its elements, Now when I keep scrolling new elements gets displayed, And since there are thousands of elements I'm deleting the old ones once the count has reached 50 elements, I'm achieving this with Javascript(injecting).

```
while (elementsCount > 50)
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> first = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@role='dialog']//ul/li[position() <= 10]//div[@class='_gzjax']/a")); // select the first 10 elements

    foreach (var item in first)
        elements.Add(item.Text); // keep the elements before deleting them

    // delete the first 10 elements
    js.ExecuteScript("for(count = 0; count < 10; count++){ " +
        "var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('_cx1ua')[0]; " +                                                   
        "elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem); }"); 
}
```

And this works great!

So at most times, there are no more than 60 elements displayed at the same time, Now when I run the program for a while and the elements scrapped are more than 10'000 Chrome's memory increases and sometimes it's more than 2gb.

I even tried to install this [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/block-image/pehaalcefcjfccdpbckoablngfkfgfgj?hl=en) to block the images from downloading(since each element has a picture attached to it) but still the same problem.

Is there something that Chrome is saving without me knowing? And is there any way to delete it and keep the current page's "status"?

Comment: It looks like you keep adding to `elements` and then never removing from it.

Comment: @TitusLucretius elements is actually just a local list, It got nothing to do with Chrome

Comment: Can you post the URL of the site you are scraping and give us more info on what you are trying to capture? Removing elements using JS seems like an inefficient way to do this. Have you tried doing this test manually? Is the memory usage different using the script vs manual?

Comment: If the elements are bind with JavaScripts events, I think remove the elements won't help because they will stay in memory as a detached DOM.

Comment: @JeffC Thank you for the comments, I'm trying to capture the usernames of an Instagram user's followers! When you click on the followers' button, A dialog box shows up, And there is a list of users inside it, So that's what I'm scrolling through.

Comment: @Buaban Exactly what I was thinking of! So is there any way to remove something completely? Even from memory?

Comment: What you are doing is against [Instagram's terms of service](https://help.instagram.com/478745558852511), `We prohibit crawling, scraping, caching or otherwise accessing any content on the Service via automated means, including but not limited to, user profiles and photos (except as may be the result of standard search engine protocols or technologies used by a search engine with Instagram's express consent).`

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is going to cause you a lot of overhead for a web scraper since it is going to rely on the memory overhead of the browser to render the content and display it to your selenium driver regardless if you see the window.

You have a few options to work around this.

### **Option 1**

I would suggest using the HtmlAgiltyPack at http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex
With this agility pack you can parse through the nodes and grab a whole lot more data and store/manipulate accordingly.

In an example from my web spider below, I am using a MongoDB C# driver to pass the data through, but the HtmlDocument you see if part of the HtmlAgility Pack

```
    BsonArray IPageCrawler.CrawlForTags(Uri url, HtmlDocument doc)
    {
        var bsonTagArray = new BsonArray();
        if (doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3]") == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        foreach (var tag in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[self::h1 or self::h2 or self::h3]"))
        {
            if (tag.InnerHtml.Contains("href"))
            {
                var innerText = _contentHandler.CleanupString(tag.InnerText);
                bsonTagArray.Add(new BsonDocument(new BsonElement(tag.Name, innerText)));
            }
            else
            {
                var tagAtt = _contentHandler.CleanupString(tag.WriteContentTo());
                bsonTagArray.Add(new BsonDocument(new BsonElement(tag.Name, tagAtt)));
            }
        }
        return bsonTagArray;
   }
```

The above code will grab all the hyperlinks from a page. I also have other methods to grab ALL of the content from any page, which so far has not crashed even at 4Gb pages (because of the downloaded zip files,ect)

### Option 2

You can keep using selenium and try executing your code utilizing a headless browser support from selenium or other 3rd party tools. http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/headless-browser-testing-selenium-webdriver/

I believe PhantomJS is a really good way to utilize a headless browser, which will reduce the memory consumption http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The reason why I didn't use HtmlAgiltyPack is that the elements are loaded with AJAX while you keep scrolling, So I need a real browser to do the job! I used PhantomJS before and I never thought it could be better than Chrome, I'll give a try and let you know

Comment: Chrome has headless browsing now

Comment: @TitusLucretius Chrome headless does not reduce memory usage(Aug 2017). So it won't help.